# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC slider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I try to create a slider in ASP.NET core, this is me home view.

I get the image from the database, but when I run the code, it displays only the first image, and I don't wont to go to next or previous. Can somebody tell me where the problem is?

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-wrap="true">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        @{
            var first = true;
        }
        @foreach (var image in Model)
        {
            <div class="carousel-item @(first ? "active" : "")">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="@WC.GalleryImagePath@image.Image_Name">
            </div>
            first = false;
        }
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
       data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button"
       data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel({
            interval: false,
            wrap: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my `HomeController`, this is the way how I get date from the SQL database. I don`t understand where the problem is, I am new in ASP.NET Core, so hopefully you can help me.

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _db = db;
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<ImageGallery> images = _db.ImageGallery.ToList();
    return View(images);
}
```

Comment: please debug your code(1.you can get data from dB 2.can get data in view 3.path image is correct 4.ajax is correct 5.etc)

Comment: Could you provide a Minimal Executable Project for us to test your project?